# Finding Fourier transform using some properties

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to solve a question of Fourier transform in which I am given two signals:$$X(jω)=δ(ω)+δ(ω-π)+δ(ω-5)\\h(t)=u(t)-u(t-2)=\begin{cases}1&0<x<2\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
I am asked to find the whether the convolution of $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ is periodic or not. Now using properties I have founded the signal $x(t)$ but I am stuck at the Fourier transform of $h(t)$.

Now I need to find its Fourier Transform using the properties and the one I got is:
$$\\x(t)=\begin{cases}1&|t|<T _1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}  \rightarrow \frac{2sin\omega T_1}{\omega}         $$
Using this property we know that the time period of the wave is 2, hence:
$$H(j\omega) = \frac{2\sin\omega2}{\omega},$$
but the one mentioned in book is
$$H(j\omega) = e^{-j\omega} \frac{2\sin\omega}{\omega}.$$
Can somebody explain that why my expression is wrong?

Comment: One could explain why the book's expression is right....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you please point out my mistake?

Comment: I cannot point out your mistake, and nor can anyone else apart from yourself, since you have not provided details of your calculation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you point out my mistake now?

Comment: Your formula works for $x(T)$ which is $1$ on the interval $(-T_1,T_1)$ and zero outside. But your $h$ is **not** of this form.